# Specify main class for sbt-resolver

Tags: sbt, spray

After upgrading to version `0.8.0` of the sbt-resolver plugin I get the following error messages after typing `sbt ~re-start`:

> [info] Application exampleJS not yet started
>
> [info] Application exampleJVM not yet started
>
> [info] Starting application exampleJVM in the background ...
>
> exampleJVM Starting example.Server.main()
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected!
>           at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)...

Hoewever, I did specify a main class in my `build.sbt`:

```
).jvmSettings(
name := "Server",
mainClass := Some("example.Server"),
...
```

My project setup is quite analogous to [this example](https://github.com/lihaoyi/workbench-example-app/tree/autowire).

However - despite this error message - the spray server is started correctly!?

But I want to get rid of this annoying message...

Comment: Do you have multiple sub-projects in your build file? You might be getting the error from one of them that doesn't have a main class.

Comment: Right. But actually in general the js-projects do not a have a `main` class.
So I don't know what to specify there...

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to suppress the warning, try replacing `reStart` in the JS subproject's build settings with a no-op:

```
import spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin.Revolver

// Assuming you're using the same name as the example you linked.
// Override the reStart task to do nothing.
val exampleJS = example.js.settings(Revolver.reStart := {})
```

Comment: This gives me this message: `error: value reStart is not a member of object sbt.Resolver`

Comment: You need the import at the top of the example you linked to (`import spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin.Revolver`). I've edited my example to include that.

Comment: Then I'm getting `value Revolver is not a member of object spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin`. I installed the spray-sbt-plugin via `addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.8.0")`.

Comment: The example code uses version `0.7.1`, which isn't quite compatible with `0.8.0`. If you've installed the plugin correctly, the `Revolver` symbol should be visible in your root `build.sbt`. If you want to access it directly, it's [in `spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin.autoImport.Revolver`](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver/blob/40783737b1ad64a35dc9b2cb726d21603ad3c80e/src/main/scala/spray/revolver/RevolverPlugin.scala#L26).

Comment: Still getting the same error after importing `spray.revolver.RevolverPlugin.autoImport._`.

Maybe I'm missing a particular `implicit`? It is not clear to me how the inner `Revolver`object should see `reStart`.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read: You should be able to use `reStart` without qualification (`reStart := {}`).